# xcode5: How to use the built in Core Image filters?

Tags: core-image, ciimage

I'm new in developing iOS Apps.
I would like to use the built in core image filters in my app. But I don't know how I can use them. I have already created the "CISephiaTon" filter. Now I would like to create the "CIPhotoEffectTransfer" filter. But I don't know how I can do this =(
Does anybody knows a good tutorial or can give me one for applying core image filters in xcode 5?

This is the filter which I want to add. Could someone give me the code of this filter?

[image]

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Observe the following code...

```
//First create a CIImage
UIImageOrientation originalOrientation = origim.imageOrientation;
data3 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(origim);
CIImage *result = [CIImage imageWithData:data3];

//Create the context
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

Apply the filter
CIFilter *colorControlsFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
    [colorControlsFilter setDefaults];
    [colorControlsFilter setValue:result forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [colorControlsFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:slySlider1.value] forKey:@"inputSaturation"];
    result = [colorControlsFilter valueForKey: @"outputImage"];

//Create CGImage with the original orientation, CIImage, and context.
CGImageRef imgRef = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:result.extent];

    //Create the new UIImage from CGImage
    theimage.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef scale:1.0 orientation:originalOrientation];
    //Release CGImageRef
    CGImageRelease(imgRef);
```

Good tutorial [Beginning Core Image](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22167/beginning-core-image-in-ios-6)

Comment: What do I have to add for ,,origim"? And what is data3?

Comment: origim is a uiimage and data3 is nsdata